# update_option to array in for loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to inside of a for loop remove a value of an array once it's been looped over?

```
$approved_posts = get_option('approved_posts');
    for($i = 0; $i <= count($approved_posts); $i++) {
        if(time() > ($approved_posts[$i]['time'] + 180)) {
            update_option('approved_posts', *remove array*);
        }
    }
```

Basically, I saved the WordPress post ID and a timestamp of when it was published, and I'd like to delete that array when the time is reached (in this case 180 seconds later).

Here's an example of the option: a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:7:"post_id";i:5003;s:4:"time";i:1551347330;}} so I'd want to remove the array from inside of the array on each loop of the for.

Comment: Am I right in thinking it's just as simple as update_option('approved_posts', array_shift()); ?